# WinRT C++ (Win10) Accessing bytes from SoftwareBitmap / BitmapBuffer

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, buffer, windows-10, uwp

To process my previewFrames of my camera in OpenCV, I need access to the raw Pixel data / bytes. So, there is the new SoftwareBitmap, which should exactly provide this.

There is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25481840/how-to-change-mediacapture-to-byte) for c#, but in visual c++ I can't get the [IMemoryBufferByteAccess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.foundation.imemorybufferreference.aspx) (see remarks) Interface working.

Code with Exceptions:

```
// Capture the preview frame
return create_task(_mediaCapture->GetPreviewFrameAsync(videoFrame))
    .then([this](VideoFrame^ currentFrame)
{
    // Collect the resulting frame
    auto previewFrame = currentFrame->SoftwareBitmap;

    auto buffer = previewFrame->LockBuffer(Windows::Graphics::Imaging::BitmapBufferAccessMode::ReadWrite);
    auto reference = buffer->CreateReference();

    // Get a pointer to the pixel buffer
    byte* pData = nullptr;
    UINT capacity = 0;

    // Obtain ByteAccess
    ComPtr<IUnknown> inspectable = reinterpret_cast<IUnknown*>(buffer);
    // Query the IBufferByteAccess interface.
    Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<IMemoryBufferByteAccess> bufferByteAccess;
    ThrowIfFailed(inspectable.As(&bufferByteAccess));     // ERROR ---> Throws HRESULT = E_NOINTERFACE

    // Retrieve the buffer data.
    ThrowIfFailed(bufferByteAccess->GetBuffer(_Out_ &pData, _Out_ &capacity));      // ERROR ---> Throws HRESULT = E_NOINTERFACE, because bufferByteAccess is null
```

I tried this too:

```
    HRESULT hr = ((IMemoryBufferByteAccess*)reference)->GetBuffer(&pData, &capacity);
```

HRESULT is ok, but I can't access pData -> Access Violation reading Memory.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Looks like you should use `Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<IMemoryBufferByteAccess>` with `reference`, not `buffer`.

Comment: Hi. Did you manage to display image in HSV color space ? I've got some artifacts ... In c# (UWP) i've got SoftwareBitmap  pass to c++, there convert SoftwareBitmap to cv::Mat , change color cpase to HSV , convert Mat to SoftwareBitmap and pass back to c#.. And set Image.Source ...    And that what i've got .. https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=357572637B8B8769!150460&authkey=!ACmXOuwLkoOyxFY&v=3&ithint=photo%2cPNG

Comment: More in detail, here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34198259/winrt-c-win10-opencv-hsv-color-space-image-display-artifacts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use reference instead of buffer in reinterpret_cast.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <wrl\wrappers\corewrappers.h>
#include <wrl\client.h>

MIDL_INTERFACE("5b0d3235-4dba-4d44-865e-8f1d0e4fd04d") 
IMemoryBufferByteAccess : IUnknown
{
    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetBuffer(
        BYTE   **value,
        UINT32 *capacity
        );
};

        auto previewFrame = currentFrame->SoftwareBitmap;

        auto buffer = previewFrame->LockBuffer(BitmapBufferAccessMode::ReadWrite);

        auto reference = buffer->CreateReference();

        ComPtr<IMemoryBufferByteAccess> bufferByteAccess;

        HRESULT result = reinterpret_cast<IInspectable*>(reference)->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&bufferByteAccess));

        if (result == S_OK)
        {
            WriteLine("Get interface successfully");

            BYTE* data = nullptr;

            UINT32 capacity = 0;

            result = bufferByteAccess->GetBuffer(&data, &capacity);

            if (result == S_OK)
            {
                WriteLine("get data access successfully, capacity: " + capacity);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks! 3 days of research and it's so simple.... your code even solved my memory allocation problem

Comment: Can you please look on my question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34198259/winrt-c-win10-opencv-hsv-color-space-image-display-artifacts

Answer (score 2):

Based on [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31850028/3697939) from @jeffrey-chen and [example](https://gist.github.com/kennykerr/f1d941c2d26227abbf762481bcbd84d3) from @kennykerr, I've assembled a tiny bit cleaner solution:

```cpp
#include <wrl/client.h>
// other includes, as required by your project

MIDL_INTERFACE("5b0d3235-4dba-4d44-865e-8f1d0e4fd04d")
IMemoryBufferByteAccess : ::IUnknown
{
    virtual HRESULT __stdcall GetBuffer(BYTE **value, UINT32 *capacity) = 0;
};

// your code:
    auto previewFrame = currentFrame->SoftwareBitmap;

    auto buffer = previewFrame->LockBuffer(BitmapBufferAccessMode::ReadWrite);

    auto bufferByteAccess= buffer->CreateReference().as<IMemoryBufferByteAccess>();
    WriteLine("Get interface successfully"); // otherwise - exception is thrown

    BYTE* data = nullptr;
    UINT32 capacity = 0;

    winrt::check_hresult(bufferByteAccess->GetBuffer(&data, &capacity));
    WriteLine("get data access successfully, capacity: " + capacity);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently accessing the raw `unsigned char* data` from each frame I obtain on a `MediaFrameReader::FrameArrived`  event without using WRL and COM...

Here it is how:

```
void MainPage::OnFrameArrived(MediaFrameReader ^reader, MediaFrameArrivedEventArgs ^args)
{
    MediaFrameReference ^mfr = reader->TryAcquireLatestFrame();
    VideoMediaFrame ^vmf = mfr->VideoMediaFrame;
    VideoFrame ^vf = vmf->GetVideoFrame();
    SoftwareBitmap ^sb = vf->SoftwareBitmap; 
    Buffer ^buff = ref new Buffer(sb->PixelHeight * sb->PixelWidth * 2);
    sb->CopyToBuffer(buff);
    DataReader ^dataReader = DataReader::FromBuffer(buffer);
    Platform::Array<unsigned char, 1> ^arr = ref new Platform::Array<unsigned char, 1>(buffer->Length);
    dataReader->ReadBytes(arr);
    // here arr->Data is a pointer to the raw pixel data
}
```

**NOTE**: The `MediaCapture` object needs to be configured with `MediaCaptureMemoryPreference::Cpu` in order to have a valid `SoftwareBitmap`

Hope the above helps someone