# WinRT C++ (Win10), opencv HSV color space, image display, artifacts

Tags: c#, opencv, windows-runtime, opencv3.0, c++-cx

My goal is to make an object tracking.

I have a UWP c# app and linked c++ windows runtime component. There I can obtain acces to opencv.

- In c#, MediaCapture return SoftwareBitmap.
- Then I pass SoftwareBitmap to c++ and convert it to opencv's Mat.
- Then `cvtColor(cvFrame, cvFrame, COLOR_BGR2HSV);`
- And then convert back to SoftwareBitmap, with BitmapPixelFormat::Bgra8 (*only Bgra8 is accepted by Software Bitmap*) and BitmapAlphaMode::Ignore

And there is what I've got [screen](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=357572637B8B8769!150460&authkey=!ACmXOuwLkoOyxFY&v=3&ithint=photo%2CPNG)

If I skip a `cvtColor` part and just convert to cv::Mat and back to SoftwareBitmap, I've got a nice image in result ...

I understand that there is a problem with image's channels ... but I've lost where to dig.
I assume that cv::Mat after `cvtColor` is right ... but I want to see intermediate steps of a picture creation. (HSV, threshold, and then result)

Any advice would be appreciated.

PS
I've tried `imwrite` but no file is created.

**Update**
Conversion from/to

```
Mat Convert(SoftwareBitmap^ from)
{
    BitmapBuffer^ bmpBuffer = from->LockBuffer(BitmapBufferAccessMode::ReadWrite);

    unsigned char* pPixels = GetPointerToPixelData(bmpBuffer->CreateReference());

    Mat mat(from->PixelHeight, from->PixelWidth, CV_8UC4);
    memcpy(mat.data, pPixels, 4 * from->PixelHeight * from->PixelWidth);

    return mat;
}

SoftwareBitmap^ Convert(Mat from)
{
    SoftwareBitmap^ sBitmap = ref new SoftwareBitmap(BitmapPixelFormat::Bgra8, from.cols, from.rows, BitmapAlphaMode::Ignore);
    BitmapBuffer^ bmpBuffer = sBitmap->LockBuffer(BitmapBufferAccessMode::ReadWrite);
    auto reference = bmpBuffer->CreateReference();

    unsigned char* dstPixels = GetPointerToPixelData(reference);
    memcpy(dstPixels, from.data, from.step.buf[1] * from.cols*from.rows);

    return sBitmap;
}

unsigned char* GetPointerToPixelData(IBuffer^ buffer)
{
    ComPtr<IBufferByteAccess> bufferByteAccess;
    ComPtr<IInspectable> insp((IInspectable*)buffer);
    ThrowIfFailed(insp.As(&bufferByteAccess));

    unsigned char* pixels = nullptr;
    ThrowIfFailed(bufferByteAccess->Buffer(&pixels));

    return pixels;
}

unsigned char* GetPointerToPixelData(IMemoryBufferReference^ reference)
{
    ComPtr<IMemoryBufferByteAccess> bufferByteAccess;

    ThrowIfFailed(reinterpret_cast<IInspectable*>(reference)->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&bufferByteAccess)));

    unsigned char* pixels = nullptr;
    unsigned int capacity = 0;
    ThrowIfFailed(bufferByteAccess->GetBuffer(&pixels, &capacity));

    return pixels;
}
```

Comment: Where does IBufferByteAccess come from?

Comment: #include <robuffer.h>
using namespace Windows::Storage::Streams;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured out the solution.

```
//convert from SoftwareBitmap to Mat
Mat cvFrame = this->Convert(frame);

//change color space
cvtColor(cvFrame, cvFrame, COLOR_BGR2HSV);

// split chanels
vector<Mat> hsvChannels(3);
split(cvFrame, hsvChannels);

//create empty chanel
Mat empty;
empty = Mat::zeros(cvFrame.rows, cvFrame.cols, CV_8UC1);

// create hsv with empty alpha
vector<Mat> channels;
channels.push_back(hsvChannels[0]); //h
channels.push_back(hsvChannels[1]); //s
channels.push_back(hsvChannels[2]); //v
channels.push_back(empty); //a

//put back to Mat
merge(channels, cvFrame);

// convert back to SoftwareBitmap 
return this->Convert(cvFrame);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't post the code that does the actual conversion from/to SoftwareBitmap/cv::Mat.

My best guess is that 3-channel image data is displayed as if there where 4 channels.

Comment: I'd like to point out that - even though it wasn't posted as an answer - my guess was right.